# How to parse an html table after being constucted by an ajax request without using done method

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my situation there is no way I can add code to done statement after the ajax call has finished. So I need some way to parse a table after an ajax request is finished.
Is there any way I can listen to the dom, so when a control is constructed or added on the page, to execute some other code?

Is there something like this?

```
$("#table_id").live('load', function(){

           ..
    });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can listen to the dom

There are [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events) but these are inconsistently supported across browsers and generally not recommended.

How about a simple [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)-provided `complete` handler for all ajax requests? That seems to be pretty close to your code example:

```
$("#table_id").ajaxComplete(function () {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I have been away from web programming for some time. Now I am back and  I will take some pain reading all these things again. Thank you